# Not Insert Properly in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to insert rows using entity framework. I used code first. I have document and author entities,

```
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PublicationName { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; } 
}


public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to add an author to a document object. I can add a document with auhtors;

```
   Document d=new Document();
   d.Authors.Add(a);
```

Then I save the context with db.SaveChanges() it can add document and its authors but I don't want it to add a new author when there is an existing one. I check this if there is no author like I look for, create a new one by a new author instance. Problem here is, ef adds one more even there is an existing author record. I don't want this if so it should get the existing authors id and add.

Is this many to many usage right? If I only add author to document authors list, is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want exactly since you did not post your author creation. But see if this helps

```
Author author =context.Authors.SingleOrDefault(o=>o.AuthorId ==authorId);

if(author ==null)
{
 author = new Author ();
 //set properties
 context.Authors.Add(author);
}

Document d=new Document();
d.Authors.Add(a);
```

Comment: And if it is already in the db but not in the context then follow the Attach method of the other answer

Comment: Use pattern similar to InsertOrUpdate for your Authors, described in the link from my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Add` for adding new entity and `Attach` for attaching existing ones.
Here's good reference explaining this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

First `Attach` your `Author` to context and then add it to `d.Authors`.